# Is there a way to edit dynamic working sets textually in Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

One of my favorite new features of Eclipse Mars is [dynamic working sets](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Setup-Eclipse/Dynamic_working_sets). It allows developers to set up rules that will automatically categorize projects into working sets.

Does anyone know of a way to textually edit this preference? I'd like to make bulk changes to my rules, but that is simply not possible in a GUI. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings are stored in ${workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.oomph.workingsets.prefs.
It's an XML-file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't an XML file, but a file that represents a string that represents XML. But this was what I was looking for. It just sucks that it has to be in such a convoluted format.